# Problems with vector <DMatch> OpenCV on Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to implement code from here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher

into an Android app. I've added nonfree modules which I complied according to this tutorial: http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android

but I'm getting errors in:

```
for 
( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ ) 
  { if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist ) 
       { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); } 
  }
```

> Field 'distance' could not be resolved
>   Invalid arguments ' // for
>   push_back

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar problems with jni. I don't know why this happens but this seems to work.

```
DMatch match;
match = matches[i];
if( match.distance < 3*min_dist ) 
   { good_matches.push_back( match); }
```

This would work. I have been getting similar vector indexing errors.